# Z-index not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I've placed 3 images in a row and I need the bottom of the first image to overlap the row beneath it. While in mobile view, I need the first image to overlap the second one. My problem is that even placing the z-index "properly" as I read in so many topics, I still don't get the desired outcome. I've changed the margins, placed the z-index value, gave the proper positioning to the images but still nothing happens.

Image 1 displays how is the current view,plus how it looks on mobile and image 2 how it should look if it works correctly.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFnJt.jpg)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmbe9.jpg)

Here is the HTML, I'm using for this specific part of the website:

```
     <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row ">   
                <div class = "three-images">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <img src = "image/sox.png" class = "img-responsive" id ="first-image">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <div class ="text-one">
                                        <span><h1>About<br>ShortsTV<br>Oscars<br></h1></span>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 ">
                            <img src = "image/2.jpg" class = "img-responsive" id ="second-image">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <div class = "text-two">
                                        <div class ="who">WHO ARE WE</div>
                                        <span1><h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br>adipiscing elit<br></h3></span1>
                                        <div class = "who">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur<br>adipiscing elit. Nulla quam velit, vulputate eu<br>
                                                                        pharetna nec, mattis ac neque. Duis vulputate</div>
                                    </div>
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Watch Trailer</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                            <img src ="image/3.jpg" class ="img-responsive" id ="third-image">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                                        <div class = "text-three">
                                            <span><h1>How to get
                                                    ShortsHD (US) or 
                                                    ShortsTV (Europe)
                                            </h1></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class= "row">
                <div class ="big-image">
                    <img src = "image/4.jpg" class= "img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the CSS I used to edit the images:

```
             #first-image{
              height: 500px;
              position:absolute;
              z-index:30;
              margin-bottom: -30px;
              }

              #second-image{
              height: 440px;
              filter: brightness(50%);
              z-index:10;

              }

              .big-image{
               position:relative;
               z-index:20;

               }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without more of your CSS, but could this be an issue of stacking contexts? If any of your images are inside other elements that have their own stacking context, you may need to have the z-index value on the parent/ancestor instead of the image itself.  notably, the `filter` rule will create a new stacking context...I see you have that here on one of the images, any chance you're also using it on one of the parent elements? Good overview here that might be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
   #first-image{
              height: 500px;
              position:absolute;
              z-index:30 !important;
              margin-bottom: -30px;
              }

              #second-image{
              height: 440px;
              filter: brightness(50%);
              z-index:10 !important;

              }

              .big-image{
               position:relative;
               z-index:20  !important;

               }
```

Comment: When I use this CSS code, the text in the first image disappears, the bottom part still doesn't show and in mobile view the entire image gets replaced by the second one.